# Accessing a font using @font-face in UIWebView from memory rather than from disk

Tags: ios, security, encryption, uiwebview, fonts

We have developed a digital book app that uses UIWebView to render pages in HMTL5. We would like to include fonts with each book. In order to comply with font licensing agreements we want to encrypt the fonts into memory and not to disk. Then we want to access the fonts in UIWebView from memory. This would provide a very acceptable level of security. Does anyone know how to get UIWebView to access the fonts from memory rather than from disk?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *inData = /* your decrypted font-file data */;
CFErrorRef error;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
    CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error)
    NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
    CFRelease(errorDescription);
}
CFRelease(font);
CFRelease(provider);
```

via [Marco](http://www.marco.org/2012/12/21/ios-dynamic-font-loading)